# About the purpose of introducing '"groups of Heisenberg type"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis, heisenberg-groups

I would like to know, can we say that the "groups of Heisenberg type" where introduced by A. Kaplan in "Kaplan, A. (1980). Fundamental solutions for a class of hypoelliptic PDE generated by composition of quadratic forms. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 258(1), 147-153."  are introduced to generalize the classical Heisenberg group $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$ or else ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't directly answer this kind of question, but I do know Aroldo Kaplan pretty well.     He taught here at UMass Amherst but retired early to return to his native Argentina (he is now at U. Cordoba).     I can send you his email address if that helps.   Meanwhile, the article itself is freely available online at http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1980-258-01/S0002-9947-1980-0554324-X/

Comment: To be a little more precise, the definition makes sense for a 2-step nilpotent Lie algebra endowed with an inner product (not necessarily invariant). Or, thus equivalently, a simply connected 2-step nilpotent Lie group endowed with a left-invariant Riemannian metric.

Comment: Also you tag "rt.representation-theory" but the author's setting seems at odds with representation theory.